# Using DB Api in a portable manner

Tags: c++, database, jdbc, cross-platform, odbc

I need to develop some kind of application and use DB in it.

Let's say i want to develop it over Windows currently, however, in a couple months i may have to migrate it to Linux.

I started reading a little bit about it, but couldn't get to point i needed.

Is there or isn't a generic/protable/standart api for using DB ?

I read there is ODBC,JDBC, iOBDC,unixODBC ? why all of these exist ?

Can someone help clearing and setting my head straight regarding the issue ?

Edit - I'm using C++ - so please advise to that direction, even though i'll appreciate inter-language/inter-platform recommendations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a bunch of C++ "wrapper" libraries for generic DB access, here's couple of top of my head:

- [SOCI](http://soci.sourceforge.net/) - modern C++ syntax, active development, plays nice with [boost](http://www.boost.org), supports multiple backends

  [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) - header-only (templates), very light-weight

Both of these grew out of Oracle-specific work, but support at least several other databases now.
Of course you can't really hide vendor differences, but that is general [law of leaky abstractions](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/LeakyAbstractions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [JDBC API](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html) in combination with a JDBC driver. Do not use the ODBC (bridge) driver.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you using [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/) if your DB load is not very heavy. you need only one header file and one source file only(amalgamation version). and It's highly portable.
I have been using it on Windows and Linux.